# How to print the content of a file without evaluating special chars?

Tags: linux, bash, files

It's a small question about Bash and Linux. I have a file with special chars like `\n`, `\r` and so on. I'm trying to print the file without using those special chars. For example if the file content is `hi \t hello` then it will print it as is (and not `hi      hello`). Using `cat file` does not do the work. Tried to look into the man of cat and I saw that I can use the -A option. It prints: `abc^Mabc`. But what is `^M`? How can I make it print as of form `\<char>`?

Comment: think you are getting this wrong. there are no "special character". the character named `carriage return` is a character that instructs the printer to go back to the beginning of the line. it is typically written as `\r`, but that is just a convention to type a character that you cannot type otherwise.

Comment: also, if you don't want carriage-returns/line-feeds, how are you planning to print more than one line?

Comment: See `man ascii`. ^M means Ctrl-M: effectively, you look for M as a printable in the right-hand column, and follow that row to the left for the corresponding control character, which is `CR '\r'`. You might look at `od -An -t c` which does 16 chars per line.

Comment: I mention that there are 256 possible 8-bit characters, of which 93 are printable and 9 more have a well-known `\r`-type representation. There are 26 further control characters with names like DEL, ENQ and DC4, and 128 that are not ASCII at all. `cat -vet` or `od` at least show a consistent and defined view.

Comment: Everything makes a whole lot more sense after `export LC_ALL=C`, because UTF-8 treats chars >= 128 as multi-byte chars.

Comment: I suspect your file contents are not what you think they are. The `man ascii` page states: `C program '\X' escapes are noted`. But those two-character escapes represent single special characters in C strings. If you write them to a file (from a C program or with echo -e)  they become like `TAB` or `CR` or `LF`. It is not `cat` that treats them as control characters -- they are already as such in the file. `od -t acx1` shows you what is *really* there, because it converts to an all-graphic notation first.

Answer (score 1):

If your file has the characters literally escaped, say, if *"hi\thello\n"* has the inverted slash and the 't' letter indicating there should be a tab character, and the slash and 'n' where should be a newline, then you have to interpret this notation and convert them into the real characters.

*[Previous solution using echo didn't work, as pointed by Paul Pedant]*

After some testing, arrived at this simple method of unquoting literally escaped characters in Bash:

```
x="$(cat filename)"
echo -en "$x"
```

To verify its operation, I created this file (with `cat > filename` then typing the lines, then `Ctrl-D` `Enter` after five spaces in the last line and other `Ctrl-D` `Enter` to close the file):

```
    This line starts with 4 leading spaces, a tab here:\t. Has a real newline (RN) here:
Newline code here:\n, six spaces and a dot:      . RN:
Return code here:\r, because the return code the first three words are hidden in the terminal.RN:
  This line starts with two spaces, then has four and a tab here:    \tRN:
This final line ends with five spaces without an ending newline:
```

Running the above command on this file shows some strange output in my terminal, as the return code causes overwriting of part of a line and doesn't show the real width of the tabs.

To check the actual characters in the output, passed it to the octal dumper `od`:

```
x="$(cat filename)"; echo -en "$x" | od -cx
```

where -c shows non printable as escaped chars and -x shows their hexadecimal code (TAB=09, RETURN=0D, NEWLINE=0A, SPACE=20, etc.), resulting in:

```
0000000                   T   h   i   s       l   i   n   e       s   t
           2020    2020    6854    7369    6c20    6e69    2065    7473
0000020   a   r   t   s       w   i   t   h       4       l   e   a   d
           7261    7374    7720    7469    2068    2034    656c    6461
0000040   i   n   g       s   p   a   c   e   s   ,       a       t   a
           6e69    2067    7073    6361    7365    202c    2061    6174
0000060   b       h   e   r   e   :  \t   .       H   a   s       a
           2062    6568    6572    093a    202e    6148    2073    2061
0000100   r   e   a   l       n   e   w   l   i   n   e       (   R   N
           6572    6c61    6e20    7765    696c    656e    2820    4e52
0000120   )       h   e   r   e   :  \n   N   e   w   l   i   n   e
           2029    6568    6572    0a3a    654e    6c77    6e69    2065
0000140   c   o   d   e       h   e   r   e   :  \n   ,       s   i   x
           6f63    6564    6820    7265    3a65    2c0a    7320    7869
0000160       s   p   a   c   e   s       a   n   d       a       d   o
           7320    6170    6563    2073    6e61    2064    2061    6f64
0000200   t   :                           .       R   N   :  \n   R   e
           3a74    2020    2020    2020    202e    4e52    0a3a    6552
0000220   t   u   r   n       c   o   d   e       h   e   r   e   :  \r
           7574    6e72    6320    646f    2065    6568    6572    0d3a
0000240   ,       b   e   c   a   u   s   e       t   h   e       r   e
           202c    6562    6163    7375    2065    6874    2065    6572
0000260   t   u   r   n       c   o   d   e       t   h   e       f   i
           7574    6e72    6320    646f    2065    6874    2065    6966
0000300   r   s   t       t   h   r   e   e       w   o   r   d   s
           7372    2074    6874    6572    2065    6f77    6472    2073
0000320   a   r   e       h   i   d   d   e   n       i   n       t   h
           7261    2065    6968    6464    6e65    6920    206e    6874
0000340   e       t   e   r   m   i   n   a   l   .   R   N   :  \n
           2065    6574    6d72    6e69    6c61    522e    3a4e    200a
0000360       T   h   i   s       l   i   n   e       s   t   a   r   t
           5420    6968    2073    696c    656e    7320    6174    7472
0000400   s       w   i   t   h       t   w   o       s   p   a   c   e
           2073    6977    6874    7420    6f77    7320    6170    6563
0000420   s   ,       t   h   e   n       h   a   s       f   o   u   r
           2c73    7420    6568    206e    6168    2073    6f66    7275
0000440       a   n   d       a       t   a   b       h   e   r   e   :
           6120    646e    6120    7420    6261    6820    7265    3a65
0000460                  \t   R   N   :  \n   T   h   i   s       f   i
           2020    2020    5209    3a4e    540a    6968    2073    6966
0000500   n   a   l       l   i   n   e       e   n   d   s       w   i
           616e    206c    696c    656e    6520    646e    2073    6977
0000520   t   h       f   i   v   e       s   p   a   c   e   s       w
           6874    6620    7669    2065    7073    6361    7365    7720
0000540   i   t   h   o   u   t       a   n       e   n   d   i   n   g
           7469    6f68    7475    6120    206e    6e65    6964    676e
0000560       n   e   w   l   i   n   e   :
           6e20    7765    696c    656e    203a    2020    2020
0000576
```

Nothing is lost and the codes are converted to the single desired chars.

PROBLEM: This simple operation can only convert small files, because Bash variables have a maximum length of 32k or so. To extend this, we have to make a loop reading convenient sized chunks of the file and converting them. For this partial block reading the utility of choice is `dd`. This is a full converter script using this method, with blocks of 16k (16384):

```
#!/bin/bash
# unescape.sh: converts escaped chars (\t) to actual chars (TAB)
# 2020.11.19 Fjor
#-------------------------------
[ -z "$2" ] \
    && echo "Use: $0 inputfile outputfile  to unescape chars (\t -> TAB)" \
    && exit
IFILE="$1"
OFILE="$2"

#-- exists input file?
[ ! -r "$IFILE" ] \
    && echo "$0: Can't read inputfile $IFILE" \
    && exit

#-- don't destroy existing output file
[ -f "$OFILE" ] \
    && read -p "$0: Output file $OFILE exists, overwrite(s/n)? " \
    && [ x"$REPLY" != xs ] \
    && exit \
    || rm -f $OFILE

let START=0
let STEP=16384
let SIZE="$(stat -c %s $IFILE)"
let NSTEPS=SIZE/STEP+1

echo -n "Converting..."
for ((n=0 ; n<$NSTEPS ; n++)) ; do
    echo -ne "\r$START bytes converted..."
    #-- ibs input block size, skip N blocks, copy count blocks
    x="$(dd if=$IFILE ibs=$STEP skip=$n count=1 2>/dev/null)"
    echo -ne "$x" >> $OFILE
    let START+=STEP
done 
echo -e "\rConversion complete ($SIZE bytes)." 

#-- end --#
```

Let's save as `unescape.sh`, `chmod u+x unescape.sh` and call it:

```
./unescape filename.txt outresult.txt
```

If the file has NULL characters, will appear warnings and the NULLs will be  ommited.

Comment: Not convinced this is sufficiently robust. `read` and `read -r` remove newlines, and leading and training space, so echo never even sees those. `read` also returns bad status if there is no trailing newline, so a final unterminated line is discarded. And `echo -e` does not convert CR to a visible `\r`, it converts a visible `\r` to an actual CR.

Comment: You're right; my simple text processing needs weren't so picky, and the question asked for a Bash solution for converting escaped chars to chars, like \t to TAB. Of course it will be better to use a more powerful language, like Python, as shown in this answer: [Process escape sequences in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python).

Comment: Deleted previous solution that have errors, as Paul Pedant said. The new is better!

Comment: Included file converter script in the modified (and working!) solution.